# Etymology of "nummy"

Tags: etymology

If a gourmand chances upon a particularly delectable meal, he might say: "Mm, nummy in my tummy!"

Where does *nummy* come from? From dictionary.com I found that *nummy* is a form of *yummy*, formed by *yum* + *-y* , where *yum* is short for *yum-yum*. Is that accurate? And, where does *yum-yum* come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie monster. See the [Rocketboom video about "om nom nom"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cqz9ZXUoUcE). Notice, in [Google timeline](http://www.google.com/search?q=nummy#q=nummy&hl=en&sa=X&tbo=1&tbs=tl:1,tll:1970,tlh:1974&prmd=iv&ei=TXb9TIHcC4Ks8AbWpoHoCg&ved=0CHcQyQEoBQ&fp=8f2884b111388cf4), that "nummy" word is not used to describe something that is yummy, until the 1970s. Cookie monster himself debuted in the 1969 premier season of *Sesame Street*. Nummy is just a another form of "nom nom", describing something as delicious.

Comment: I've seen *'om nom nom'* as the onomatopoeic sound of eating, and the derivative from that of *"nom"* - but **never** *nummy*.

Comment: Being around pre-schoolers a lot, I can assure you _nummy_ is very much alive and well.

Answer (score 5):

*Nummy* as a baby-talk version of *yummy* predates *Sesame Street*, probably by some decades. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* (2001) puts its origin (as a variant of *yummy*) in the early twentieth century.

I found two possible (though not entirely unambiguous) instances of *nummy* for *yummy* in a Google Books search from the years 1915 through 1921. From Lucy O'Connor, [*Mary's Meadow Papers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mary_s_Meadow_papers/-dRCAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22nummy%22) (1915):

> …and they carry little Dossie, sucking her "**nummy**," and say "It doesn't matter bringing Dossie, because she is too young to eat anything"; and they know I shan't mind having Rosie Matthews, because her mother is ill ; and they think we'll like poor Katie Tipton, because she's lame and walks with a crutch; and Gerty Collier is staying with the Ridlers, and goes back home to London on Monday, and she wanted to come because she didn't even know what a tent-party was.

From John Galsworthy, "[A Stoic](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Five_Tales/sQOUHPjiAfIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22isn%27t+it+nummy%22&pg=PA168&printsec=frontcover)," in *Five Tales* (1918):

> "DEAREST GUARDY,—I'm sorry this is such a mangy little valentine; I couldn't go out to get it because I've got a beastly cold, so I asked Jock, and the pig bought this. The satin is simply scrumptious. If you don't come and see me in it sometime soon, I shall come and show it to you. I wish I had a moustache, because my top lip feels just like a matchbox, but it's rather ripping to have breakfast in bed. Mr. Pillin's taking us to the theatre the day after to-morrow evening. Isn't it **nummy**! I'm going to have rum and honey for my cold. Good-bye, Your PHYLLIS."

The earliest unmistakable instance that Google Books returns, however, is from Charles Morris, [*Signification and Significance*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Writings_on_the_General_Theory_of_Signs/3lW1BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22saying+nummy+num%22&pg=PA405&printsec=frontcover) (1964), partially reproduced in Charles Morris, "Writings on the General Theory of Signs* (1971):

> In the case of appraisive signs, the interpretant would be a  disposition to act toward a designated object as if it would be satisfying or unsatisfying. Thus if a mother tries to get her child to swallow a teaspoonful of castor oil by saying "**nummy num**", the child is set for something he will favor. Since he does not like it when he tastes it, and if the mother continues to talk like this in a variety of situations, the term '**nummy num**' will change from a positive appraisive sign to a negative appraisive sign—or the child will come to regard his mother as a liar.

The main complication with the early examples of *nummy* is that several nineteenth-century sources use *nummy* to refer to numbness or as slang for *numbskull*.

Thus, R. Oliver Heslop, "[Dialect Speech in Northumberland](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lectures_Delivered_to_the_Literary_and_P/bNQGAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22nummy%22)," in *Lectures on Northumbrian History Literature and Art* (1898) reports:

> But he [the goodman of Northumberland] would *liever* not send the *scrat* of a pen to the *maister*: his hand was so stiff and ***nummy***.

And Heslop again, in *[Northumberland Words](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Northumberland_Words/InwKAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22numby,+nummy%22&pg=PA507&printsec=frontcover)* (1893–1894), includes this entry:

> NUMBY, NUMMY, a numskull. "Co'by! ye ***numby***."

Further, as noted "[Exclamations in American English](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dialect_Notes/lxwOAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nummy+num%22+%22humming+or+joy%22&pg=PA274&printsec=frontcover)" in *Dialect Notes* (1924), the phrase "num, num, nummy, num" can signify "humming or joy," as indeed happens in Zona Gale, [*Miss Lulu Bett*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Miss_Lulu_Bett/0SQeAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22nummy%22) (1921):

> "**Num, num, nummy-num**!" sang the child Monona loudly, and was hushed by both parents in simultaneous exclamation which rivaled this lyric outburst. They were alone at table. ...
>
> ...
>
> There was a moment's silence into which Monona injected a loud "**Num, num, nummy-num**," as if she were the burden of an Elizabethan lyric.

---

**Update (May 16, 2020)**

A much earlier instance of "nummy" clearly used in the sense of "yummy" appears in Nancy Wynne, "[Just Gossip About People](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045211/1918-09-20/ed-1/seq-15/#words=nummy%2BNummy)," in the *[Philadelphia, Pennsylvania] Evening Public Ledger* (September 20, 1918):

> You never tasted anything like the waffles. Umh—umh! I want some more today. And you had to wait quite a while, too, yesterday, because the stoves were not set up in time. However, I got mine at 1 o'clock, and **nummy**! **nummy**! but they were good.

And from Henry Hanemann, "['Children Who Prefer Sweetmeats...'](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_Magazine/bC1HAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nummy%22&pg=PA1091&printsec=frontcover)" in *Life Magazine* (December 9, 1920):

> "See!" cooed the nurse. "See what nursie has for nice itty gentyman's tea. Ni-ice, twee-et, oaty mee-al."
>
> Horace looked over at Albemarle. But that "itty gentyman" had already rushed over to the diminutive supper table, and was beating frantically upon it with his silver spoon.
>
> "**Nummy**, **nummy**, **nummy**!” he clamored shockingly. "Ni-ice oaty meal. **Nummy**, **nummy**, **nummy**!"
>
> "**Nummy**, **nummy**, **nummy**!" agreed Horace heartily, taking his place opposite his host.

So evidently the expression has been in use for more than a century among some English speakers.

Answer (score 2):

"Nummy" sounds to me like a [baby talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk) version of "yummy". But I don't know where "yummy" comes from!

Comment: Search this very site, [and you will find](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/).